# Different behavior of boost::future and std::future

Tags: c++, boost

To be specific, `boost::future` doesn't seem to block in the destructor. And [boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.unique_future.destructor) didn't mention it. However `std::future` did mention [it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/%7Efuture).

If I want to chain some `.then()` to `boost::future` I also need to chain a `.get()` call at the end to force the temporary object to block to get the correct behavior. Is that the right way of using it?

```cpp
void a()
{
    boost::async([] {
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds{1});
        std::cout << "Finished sleeping\n";
        return 1;
    });
    std::cout << "End of a()\n";
}
void b()
{
    std::async([] {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{1});
        std::cout << "Finished sleeping\n";
        return 1;
    });
    std::cout << "End of b()\n";
}
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    a();//No finished sleeping printed
    std::cout << "End of main()\n";
}
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    b();//finished sleeping will print
    std::cout << "End of main()\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html

> The returned futures behave as the ones returned from boost::async, the destructor of the future object returned from then will block. This could be subject to change in future versions.

(2015) https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/thread/changes.html

> Version 4.5.0 - boost 1.58
> Fixed Bugs:
> #10968 The futures returned by async() and future::then() are not blocking.

(2017) https://github.com/boostorg/thread/issues/194

> I'm aware of the issue. Boost.thread did it by design following std::async and the first proposals of std::future::then.
>
> The problem is that changing the behavior (even if it is not desired in some contexts) would be a breaking change. I would need to crate a new version, but Idon't want to create a new version using compiler flags as this has become a nightmare to maintain.
>
> So I will need to create a boost/thread_v5 which will produce different binaries lib_boost_thread_v5.a. Boost.Threads is not structured this way, and this will mean a lot of work.
> This is the single way to avoid breaking changes, but before doing that I would like to enumerate all the breaking changes that should be on this new version.

It seems the destructor of future object returned from `async` has really changed to non-blocking at some time point after 2017, so you **should use `.get()` to block**.

---

I can not make it block because:

- `BOOST_THREAD_FUTURE_BLOCKING`(not documented) is not `#define`d in all cases;
- if you `#define BOOST_THREAD_FUTURE_BLOCKING` manually, you can see that `~future_async_shared_state_base()` will be called when the `future` is destroyed **and** the lambda passed to async has finished running (i.e. when the `boost::shared_ptr`'s use_count drops from 2 to 1 to 0), so the destructor of future object returned from `async` (when the `boost::shared_ptr`'s use_count drops from 2 to 1) will still not block.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/boost/thread/detail/config.hpp

```cpp
#if BOOST_THREAD_VERSION>=5
//#define BOOST_THREAD_FUTURE_BLOCKING

#if ! defined BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_EXECUTORS \
 && ! defined BOOST_THREAD_DONT_PROVIDE_EXECUTORS
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_EXECUTORS
#endif

#else
//#define BOOST_THREAD_FUTURE_BLOCKING
#define BOOST_THREAD_ASYNC_FUTURE_WAITS
#endif
```

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/boost/thread/future.hpp
in `async`:

```cpp
          void init(BOOST_THREAD_FWD_REF(Fp) f)
          {
#ifdef BOOST_THREAD_FUTURE_BLOCKING
            this->thr_ = boost::thread(&future_async_shared_state::run, static_shared_from_this(this), boost::forward<Fp>(f));
#else
            boost::thread(&future_async_shared_state::run, static_shared_from_this(this), boost::forward<Fp>(f)).detach();
#endif
          }
```

when the `future` is destroyed **and** the lambda passed to async has finished running:

```cpp
          ~future_async_shared_state_base()
          {
#ifdef BOOST_THREAD_FUTURE_BLOCKING
            join();
#elif defined BOOST_THREAD_ASYNC_FUTURE_WAITS
            unique_lock<boost::mutex> lk(this->mutex);
            this->waiters.wait(lk, boost::bind(&shared_state_base::is_done, boost::ref(*this)));
#endif
          }
```

---

C++20 has moved to coroutine which is able to split control flow in more complex cases than future.then: [CppCon 2015: Gor Nishanov “C++ Coroutines - a negative overhead abstraction"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fu0gx-xseY). You can try libraries like cppcoro or boost.fiber and pause the task function inside complex control structures (e.g. `co_await` inside `if` inside `while` inside `for`).

C++23 Executor TS: in initial versions of [A Unified Executors Proposal for C++](https://wg21.link/P0443) there were `OneWayExecutor` `execute`(fire-and-forget) `TwoWayExecutor` `twoway_execute`(return a future) `then_execute`(take a future and a function, return a future) etc but in recent versions they were replaced by sender and receiver.